# What would be the best word to use for the "specificity" of data points?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been stuck for about 20 minutes while working on a reporting application because I can't think of what to call this property. When requesting a report, the user must specify a start date, an end date as well as the "specificity" of the data points, for example "day", "week" etcetera. I have considered calling it "specificity" or "unit size", but I feel that none of those words properly convey the meaning of the property. What word (or words) would best describe the property?

Comment: Are you looking for _precision_? Or _granularity_?

Comment: @BraddSzonye: Precision makes sense! Very good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Precision*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precision) has two meanings related to data collection:

> 2 the ability of a measurement to be reproduced consistently
>
> 3 (*mathematics*) the number of significant digits to which a value may be measured reliably

While your usage is not a precise fit for either meaning, it should be intuitive enough for the application's users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [***periodicity***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/periodicity)
*1. The quality or state of being periodic; recurrence at regular intervals.*

Another option is to use *frequency* of data.